# Prolog assignment fails

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to build a simple greatest common divisor (cmmdc) in prolog and, for the following code, I get a fail on newY =  X mod Y. Can anyone help me out?

```
% cmmdc(X: intreg, Y: intreg, Ret: intreg)
% (i, i, o), (i, i, i)

cmmdc(X, 0, X):- !.
cmmdc(X, Y, Ret):-
    newY = X mod Y,
    cmmdc(Y, newY, Ret).
```

Answer (score 1):

`newY` starts with a lowercase letter, so it is an atom instead of a varaible.

`=` is unification, not arithmetic.

The atom `newY` is not the same as the term `mod(X,Y)` so unification fails.

Use `NewY is X mod Y` instead.